# ci testing gitlab php

Tags: php, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

Hi i am trying to run ci tests for a php application on gitlab.

Here is my yml file

```
image: php:7.2-apache

cache:
 paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
 - apt-get update -yqq
 - apt-get install -yqq curl
 - curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php

test:
 script:
  - cd src
  - /vendor/bin/phpunit test.php
```

I am getting the following error, i am able to run phpunit test.php on my docker. any help is much apricated.

```
$ /vendor/bin/phpunit test.php
/bin/bash: line 102: /vendor/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: The docker container that you are running the CI pipeline does not have `phpunit` installed on it. You could either include it in a custom image and use that for your CI pipeline or install it (probably using `composer`) before your `test` stage

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I am completely new to this so apricate your help. I have tried running this command in the docker terminal composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^7 but im getting errors. I have also tried this command in the before script but its saying composer is not recognised.

Comment: Getting `composer is not recognised` in the before script means composer needs to be installed as well. You might want to consider using this image instead: https://hub.docker.com/r/phpunit/phpunit